# how to downgrade Perl to 5.8.8?

Tags: amazon-ami, downgrade

I have Amazon instance (Amazon Linux AMI release 2011.02.1.1 (beta),2.6.35.11-83.9.amzn1.i686) and I want to downgrade Perl Version from v5.10.1 to v5.8.8, but when compile perl 5.8.8 I got this error:

```
asm/page.h: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [SysV.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/perl-5.8.8/ext/IPC/SysV'
```

how can solve this problem ?

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade? The Perl 5.10 delaty says there is no reason to: http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.1/pod/perl5100delta.pod#DESCRIPTION

Comment: because my application was built on perl 5.8.8 and when moved it in new version I facing some problems

Comment: Oh, thats interesting, at that should not happen. As i have no clue from Amazon AMI, not as an answer: according to your error message, you are missing the linux headers. But no idea how to install.

Comment: the kernel-headers-2.6.35.11-83.9.amzn1.i686 already installed, but doesn't contain the page.h

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after looking into the perl mailing lists: You want find a good way to compile the old Perl with your new kernel. The `asm/page.h` isn't part of the kernel header, and the `IPC::SysV`, shipped with perl 5.8.8 is to old.

Here are some suggestions in the mailinglist:

http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2010/03/msg158201.html

But maybe you should have a look at the http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.1/pod/perl5100delta.pod, so maybe you could find a simple way to make your program run.

Perl 5.8.8 is end of liftem, the current stable is 5.12, the current testing 5.14